# AWS EKS managed nodegroup created with CloudFormation fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

I've created a VPC and EKS cluster using CloudFormation, and when I try to create an AWS managed nodegroup through CloudFormation, it fails to create with the error message: `Nodegroup test-ng failed to stabilize: [{Code: NodeCreationFailure,Message: Unhealthy nodes in the kubernetes cluster`. I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact issue, but my setup is based on the AWS docs. For reference, I want a VPC with 3 public and 3 private subnets, with the managed nodegroup deployed to the private subnets. Here are the templates I've used to deploy everything:

VPC Template:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'EKS VPC - Private and Public Subnets'

Parameters:

  VpcName:
    Type: String
    Default: EKS-VPC
    Description: The name of the VPC

  VpcBlock:
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/16
    Description: The CIDR range for the VPC. This should be a valid private (RFC 1918) CIDR range.

  PrivateSubnet01Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/19
    Description: CidrBlock for private subnet 01 within the VPC

  PrivateSubnet02Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.32.0/19
    Description: CidrBlock for private subnet 02 within the VPC
  
  PrivateSubnet03Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.64.0/19
    Description: CidrBlock for private subnet 03 within the VPC

  PublicSubnet01Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.128.0/20
    Description: CidrBlock for public subnet 01 within the VPC

  PublicSubnet02Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.144.0/20
    Description: CidrBlock for public subnet 02 within the VPC

  PublicSubnet03Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.160.0/20
    Description: CidrBlock for public subnet 02 within the VPC

Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
      -
        Label:
          default: "Main"
        Parameters:
          - VpcName
      -
        Label:
          default: "Network Configuration"
        Parameters:
          - VpcBlock
          - PublicSubnet01Block
          - PublicSubnet02Block
          - PublicSubnet03Block
          - PrivateSubnet01Block
          - PrivateSubnet02Block
          - PrivateSubnet03Block

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock:  !Ref VpcBlock
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Ref VpcName

  InternetGateway:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"

  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment"
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Public Subnets RT
      - Key: Network
        Value: Public

  PrivateRouteTable01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Private Subnet 01 RT
      - Key: Network
        Value: Private

  PrivateRouteTable02:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Private Subnet 02 RT
      - Key: Network
        Value: Private

  PrivateRouteTable03:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Private Subnet 03 RT
      - Key: Network
        Value: Private

  PublicRoute:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PrivateRoute01:
    DependsOn:
    - VPCGatewayAttachment
    - NatGateway01
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable01
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway01

  PrivateRoute02:
    DependsOn:
    - VPCGatewayAttachment
    - NatGateway02
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable02
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway02

  PrivateRoute03:
    DependsOn:
    - VPCGatewayAttachment
    - NatGateway03
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable03
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway03

  NatGateway01:
    DependsOn:
    - NatGatewayEIP1
    - PublicSubnet01
    - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt 'NatGatewayEIP1.AllocationId'
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet01
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub '${VpcName}-NatGateway01'

  NatGateway02:
    DependsOn:
    - NatGatewayEIP2
    - PublicSubnet02
    - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt 'NatGatewayEIP2.AllocationId'
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet02
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub '${VpcName}-NatGateway02'

  NatGateway03:
    DependsOn:
    - NatGatewayEIP3
    - PublicSubnet03
    - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt 'NatGatewayEIP3.AllocationId'
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet03
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub '${VpcName}-NatGateway03'

  NatGatewayEIP1:
    DependsOn:
    - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGatewayEIP2:
    DependsOn:
    - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGatewayEIP3:
    DependsOn:
    - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  PublicSubnet01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Public Subnet 01
    Properties:
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '0'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PublicSubnet01Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${VpcName}-PublicSubnet01"
      - Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
        Value: 1

  PublicSubnet02:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Public Subnet 02
    Properties:
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '1'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PublicSubnet02Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${VpcName}-PublicSubnet02"
      - Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
        Value: 1

  PublicSubnet03:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Public Subnet 03
    Properties:
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '2'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PublicSubnet03Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${VpcName}-PublicSubnet03"
      - Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
        Value: 1

  PrivateSubnet01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Private Subnet 01
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '0'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PrivateSubnet01Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${VpcName}-PrivateSubnet01"
      - Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
        Value: 1

  PrivateSubnet02:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Private Subnet 02
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '1'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PrivateSubnet02Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${VpcName}-PrivateSubnet02"
      - Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
        Value: 1
  
  PrivateSubnet03:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Private Subnet 03
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '2'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PrivateSubnet03Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${VpcName}-PrivateSubnet03"
      - Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
        Value: 1

  PublicSubnet01RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet01
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  PublicSubnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet02
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  PublicSubnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet03
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  PrivateSubnet01RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet01
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable01

  PrivateSubnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet02
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable02

  PrivateSubnet03RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet03
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable03

  ControlPlaneSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Cluster communication with worker nodes
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  WorkerNodeSshSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: SG for ssh access to worker nodes in managed nodegroup
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

Outputs:

  PublicSubnetIds:
    Description: Public Subnets IDs in the VPC
    Value: !Join [ ", ", [ !Ref PublicSubnet01, !Ref PublicSubnet02, !Ref PublicSubnet03 ] ]

  PrivateSubnetIds:
    Description: Private Subnets IDs in the VPC
    Value: !Join [ ", ", [ !Ref PrivateSubnet01, !Ref PrivateSubnet02, !Ref PrivateSubnet03 ] ]

  ControlPlaneSecurityGroups:
    Description: Security group for the cluster control plane communication with worker nodes
    Value: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref ControlPlaneSecurityGroup ] ]

  WorkerNodeSshSecurityGroup:
    Description: SG for ssh access to worker nodes in managed nodegroup
    Value: !Ref WorkerNodeSshSecurityGroup

  VpcId:
    Description: The VPC Id
    Value: !Ref VPC
```

IAM Roles Template:

```
Mappings:
  ServicePrincipals:
    aws-cn:
      ec2: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
    aws-us-gov:
      ec2: ec2.amazonaws.com
    aws:
      ec2: ec2.amazonaws.com

Resources:

  eksClusterRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - eks.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy

  NodeInstanceRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - !FindInMap [ServicePrincipals, !Ref "AWS::Partition", ec2]
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
      Path: /

Outputs:

  eksClusterRoleArn:
    Description: The role that Amazon EKS will use to create AWS resources for Kubernetes clusters
    Value: !GetAtt eksClusterRole.Arn

  NodeInstanceRole:
    Description: The node instance role
    Value: !GetAtt NodeInstanceRole.Arn
```

EKS Cluster Template:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'EKS Production-Grade Cluster'

Parameters:

  KubernetesVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: The EKS supported Kubernetes version for your cluster
    Default: 1.19
    AllowedValues:
      - 1.19
      - 1.18
      - 1.17

  ClusterName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the cluster

  ControlPlaneClusterRoleArn:
    Type: String
    Description: The eksClusterRole Arn to use for the eks cluster (control plane)

  ControlPlaneSubnetIds:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Description: Register your public and private subnets with your EKS managed control plane

  SecurityGroupIds:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
    Description: The security group(s) for the cross-account elastic network interfaces that Amazon EKS creates to use to allow communication between your nodes and the Kubernetes control plane.

Resources:
  
  EKSManagedControlPlane:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Cluster
    Properties:
      KubernetesNetworkConfig: 
        ServiceIpv4Cidr: 172.16.0.0/12
      Name: !Ref ClusterName
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroupIds
        SubnetIds: !Ref ControlPlaneSubnetIds
      RoleArn: !Ref ControlPlaneClusterRoleArn
      Version: !Ref KubernetesVersion
```

Managed Nodegroup Template:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'EKS Production-Grade Nodegroup'

Parameters:

  KubernetesVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: The EKS supported Kubernetes version for your cluster
    Default: 1.19
    AllowedValues:
      - 1.19
      - 1.18
      - 1.17

  ClusterName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the cluster

  NodeInstanceRoleArn:
    Type: String
    Description: The NodeInstanceRole Arn to use for the eks nodegroup (managed data plane)

  DataPlanePrivateSubnetIds:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Description: Private subnets for your Amazon EKS data plane nodes

  WorkerNodeGroupName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the node group for the worker nodes in the data plane. Right now we are only supporting 1 node group per cluster.

  WorkerNodesInstanceType:
    Type: String
    Description: The instance type for the worker nodes in the data plane. Right now we are only supporting 1 instance type for all worker nodes.
    Default: t3.medium
    AllowedValues:
      - t3.small
      - t3.medium
      - t3.large
      - m5.large
      - m5.xlarge
      - c5.large
      - c5.xlarge

  WorkerNodesEc2SshKey:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Description: The Amazon EC2 SSH key that provides access for SSH communication with the nodes in the managed node group

  SourceSecurityGroupsForWorkerNodes:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
    Description: The security groups that are allowed SSH access (port 22) to the nodes. If you specify an Amazon EC2 SSH key but do not specify a source security group when you create a managed node group, then port 22 on the nodes is opened to the internet.

Resources:

  EKSManagedDataPlane:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Nodegroup
    Properties:
      AmiType: AL2_x86_64
      CapacityType: ON_DEMAND
      ClusterName: !Ref ClusterName
      ForceUpdateEnabled: false
      InstanceTypes:
        - !Ref WorkerNodesInstanceType
      NodegroupName: !Ref WorkerNodeGroupName
      NodeRole: !Ref NodeInstanceRoleArn
      RemoteAccess: 
        Ec2SshKey: !Ref WorkerNodesEc2SshKey
        SourceSecurityGroups: !Ref SourceSecurityGroupsForWorkerNodes
      ScalingConfig:
        DesiredSize: 3
        MaxSize: 4
        MinSize: 3
      Subnets: !Ref DataPlanePrivateSubnetIds
      Version: !Ref KubernetesVersion
```

For the EKS Cluster template, I use the eksClusterRole ARN for the EKS cluster parameter, and I pass in all 6 subnet ids (public and private) from the VPC template output when creating the cluster. The SG id I pass in from the VPC ControlPlaneSecurityGroups output field as well.

For the Managed Nodegroup template I only pass it the private subnet ids from the VPC output, the ssh security group id from the VPC output, and the NodeInstanceRole ARN. I have ensured that the cluster name matches what I have given for the EKS Cluster template when creating that.

I plan on configuring the VPC CNI plugin to use IAM Roles for Service accounts once the cluster and managed nodegroup are setup, which is why I have left the policy for the CNI off of that IAM role.